# Datetime conversion in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I am using SQLite database, where I need some help

```
select Value from SdVarTbl where Name='DateCreated.Sd'
```

This query returns a single row and single columns.
Which is a varchar type in database.

[image]

And another query

```
select ComputerName, LastCheckIn from ClientB
```

which returns

[image]

**My query:**
I want to show another column say "Difference", which will print the date difference between and first query and each value in the second query.

HOW to achieve that. I have tried to use datetime, strftime function, but couldn't succeed till now.

Comment: select 
ComputerName, 
datetime(LastCheckIn) as LastCheckIn,
(select strftime(Value) from SdVarTbl where Name='DateCreated.Sd') - datetime(LastCheckIn) as Difference
from ClientB

Comment: My above query didn't work, I don't know where it is getting wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want the difference as a number of days, so I suggest using the `julianday()` function. It's result is the number of days (since noon in Greenwich on November 24, 4714 B.C, but this doesn't really matter if you use it to calculate differences) :

```
select c.ComputerName,
  c.LastCheckIn,
  julianday(c.LastCheckIn) - julianday(v.value) as diff_days
from ClientB c
join SdVarTbl v
  on v.Name='DateCreated.Sd'
```

Comment: Yes I want the difference in number of days.

Comment: The `diff_days` returned by the query is decimal, you need to round it if you want an integer